# Sequence with CodeActivities with WorkflowInvoker's input arguments doesn't work?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

Why is it not possible to pass the arguments to CodeActivity via WorkflowInvoker's input dictionary, if the activities are within a Sequence? The WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(sequence, dict) method throws the following exception:

> *Additional information: The values provided for the root activity's arguments did not satisfy the root activity's requirements:*
>
> *'Sequence': The following keys from the input dictionary do not map to arguments and must be removed: Arg.  Please note that argument names are case sensitive.*

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sequence = new Sequence();
            var start = new Start();
            var end = new End();

            sequence.Activities.Add(start);
            sequence.Activities.Add(end);

            var dict = new Dictionary();
            dict["Arg"] = "Debug text.";

            WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(sequence, dict);
        }
    }

    public class Start : CodeActivity
    {
        public InArgument Arg { get; set; }

        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(Arg.Get(context));
        }
    }

    public class End : CodeActivity
    {
        public InArgument Arg { get; set; } 

        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(Arg.Get(context));
        }
    }

// ************** Second example with custom sequence *************************

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var seq = new MySequence();
            seq.Activities.Add(new Last());
            seq.Activities.Add(new First());

            var dict = new Dictionary();
            dict["Arg"] = "Text";

            WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(seq, dict);
        }
    }

    public class First : CodeActivity
    {
        public InArgument Arg { get; set; }

        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
            var val = Arg.Get(context);
        }
    }

    public class Last : CodeActivity
    {
        public InArgument Arg { get; set; }

        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
            var val = Arg.Get(context);
        }
    }

    public class MySequence : NativeActivity
    {
        public InArgument Arg { get; set; }

        public Collection Activities = new Collection();

        protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
        {
            base.CacheMetadata(metadata);
            metadata.SetChildrenCollection(Activities);
        }

        protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
        {
            foreach (var activity in Activities)
                context.ScheduleActivity(activity);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code activities take their arguments from the container they are in not the input dictionary.  The container needs to have an in argument matching the one in the dictionary.

Sequences don't accept arguments so you wrap them in an Activity.
An Activity constructed as below is a worklfow

```
public class MyCodeWorkflow : Activity 
{
public InArgument<string> inMSG { get; set; }
public OutArgument<string> outMSG { get; set; }

public MyCodeWorkflow() 
{
    this.Implementation = () => new Sequence {
        Activities = 
        {
            new WriteLine
            {
                Text=new InArgument<string>((activityContext)=>this.inMSG.Get(activityContext))
            },

            new Assign<string>
            {
                To=new ArgumentReference<string>("outMSG"),
                Value=new InArgument<string>
                    (
                        (activityContext)=>this.inMSG.Get(activityContext)
                    )
            }
        }
    };
}
}

//host
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
     IDictionary<string, object> input = new Dictionary<string, object>();
     input.Add("inMSG","hello");
     IDictionary<string, object> output = new Dictionary<string, object>();
     MyCodeWorkflow activity = new MyCodeWorkflow();
     output = WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(activity,input);
     Console.WriteLine(output["outMSG"]);       
 }
```

The code above was taken from  http://xhinker.com/post/WF4Authoring-WF4-using-imperative-code%28II%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Now it makes sense, why it behaves so. Is there a way how to pass or get the "container" context to the child activity, that I could avoid creating the argument instance out of the child activity? In other words, setting the Text property of the WriteLine activity from the MyCodeWorkflow constructor... I'd like to have it set by the activity workflow, so that the MyCodeWorkflow class would not have to care whether there are some arguments within the child activities.

Comment: I'm not totally sure I understand the question. MyCodeWorkflow is not creating the arguments out of the child.  The arguments are the public arguments set on the class.  You could create MyCodeWorkflow and miss out creating the child activities and you would still have the In/Out arguments for MyCodeWorkflow.  If you create an empty sequence Sequence and make it as public then you could add the child activities to that in the same way you did in your first example.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. I didn't know how to provide an extra code example without editing my first example. So please look at the first example under the comment line "Second example". My question should have rather been like: "Why child activities cannot access the arguments of the "parent" activity?" In the second example the First and Last activities get null at "var val = Arg.Get(context)"

Comment: @Richard210363 this might be an old topic but I can't find any related queries to this subject... I'm getting this error when I run your code: https://paste.mod.gg/unkidyzpimhx/0

Comment: @Laurian Avrigeanu  Sorry, this is so old I barely remember what it did.  The error is saying outMSG is missing.  Make sure you have this line correct in your code To=new ArgumentReference<string>("outMSG"),